# What are invalid statements in the following C++ template program?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can I pass more than one argument of different datatypes to the same function when I use a template like this?

```
template <typename T> T func(T a, T str)
{
  T strx = str + 'x';
  return strx;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  int x;
  string str = "hai";
  str = func(a, str);
  cout << x;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with a single template parameter. For example you passed an `int` and a `string` as arguments to `func`. What type would `T` be in this case? You'll need to instead use 2 separate template types to define each, for example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 func(T1 a, T2 str)
```

---

Now, it looks like what you're really trying to do is append a value to a `string`. You could accomplish that using a [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream), but you'd only need one template argument:

```
template<typename T>
string func(T a, string& str) {
    return static_cast<ostringstream&>(ostringstream(str, ios_base::ate) << a).str();
}
```

Or, if you knew the types you were going to append were always numeric types you could use: [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to accomplish the same thing.

If you want to add two unrelated types you could do:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 func(T1 a, T2 str) {
    stringstream sstream;

    sstream << a;

    T2 t2a;

    sstream >> t2a;

    return str + t2a;
}
```

This [obviously work](http://ideone.com/fpXpxA) for values like `func(string{"42"}, 13)` but I can't work for stuff like `func(string{"a"}, 13)` cause `stringstream` doesn't know how to convert `"a"` to an `int`. So use this with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by adding templates arguments for its one of the desired types, as bellow:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> T2 func(T1 a,T2 str) {
 // ... 
}
```

Comment: I'd use `auto` for the return type and `strx`, as you don't necessarily know what the type of `str+'x'` is.

Comment: @TartanLlama `auto` without trailing return type isn't  C++11.

Comment: Maybe `typename std::common_type<T2,char>::type func(T1 a, T2 str)`